# How to teleport entities named with a space?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't teleport entities with names like 'big boy', "reverse flash", since in the `/tp` command both "big boy" or "big_boy" are not working.

```
/tp @e[type=horse,name=CROSS BONE] -978 118 -841 
/tp @e[type=horse,name=CROSS_BONE] -978 118 -841
```

Nothing works. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I suppose this is Minecraft Java, since you didn't tag it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use testfor with a mob with a two-word name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204810/how-to-use-testfor-with-a-mob-with-a-two-word-name)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
/tp @e [type=horse, name="CROSS_BONE"] -978 118 -841
```